# Switch Theme mode with a Switch Flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the theme of my app. First of all, I initialized the theme colors:

```
ThemeData _lightTheme = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.white
);

ThemeData _darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(25, 29, 30, 100),
  buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
    buttonColor: Colors.amber,
  )
);
bool _light = true;
```

then I check the theme, that is currently set

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: _light ? _lightTheme : _darkTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
      drawer: SideBar(),
      appBar: AppBar(
```

the body of the main code looks like this:

```
        title: Text('To-Do-App'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 152, 185, 100),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(25, 29, 30, 100),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: connectToFirebase(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          else {
            // When stream exists, use Streambilder to wait for data
            return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(

              stream: database.getTodos(),

              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                else {
                  // resolve stream... Stream<DocumentSnapshot> -> DocumentSnapshot -> Map<String, bool>
                  Map<String, dynamic> items = snapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      String key = items.keys.elementAt(i);
                      return ToDoItem(
                        key,
                        items[key],
                            () => deleteItem(key),
                            () => toggleDone(key, items[key]),
                      );
                    }
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          }
        }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: newEntry,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 152, 185, 100),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

finaly I want to change the App Theme with a switch (

```
        child: Switch(value: _light, onChanged: (state) {
          setState(() {
            _light = state;
          });
        }),
```

)
My problem is, that I want to integrate the switch in another class (settings page). It´s looks like this:

```
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}
ThemeData _lightTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primaryColor: Colors.white
);

ThemeData _darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(25, 29, 30, 100)
);
bool _light = true;

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: _light ? _lightTheme : _darkTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
      drawer: SideBar(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Settings'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 152, 185, 100),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(25, 29, 30, 100),
      body: Center(
        child: Switch(value: _light, onChanged: (state) {
          setState(() {
            _light = state;
          });
        }),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

but the switch I have in the settings class doesn´t work (can´t tap on it)
My Question is, if this is even possible, that the initialation of the dark mode is in the settings page class and not in the main class and how can I get the switch to work?

Comment: DId you tried changing themes with provider?

Comment: No, I don´t know what providers are

Comment: Provider is the Global State management technique(Package). You should learn Global state management after that use provider for global state management. see package [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) on pub.dart. That will be efficient way to use themes in your app